# How to Create widget in flutter using class

Tags: flutter, class, widget, stateful

I'm new, both in dart and in the community, and i need help, i'm starting larn about flutter and widgets is confused for me, so i'm separated the widget in class, but the NumberPicker need metod setState(() for update the value when is chang, but in separed class it don't work, I believe that is inherited from StatefulWidget class, how i resolve this problem?

thanks for answer

i try inherit the StatefulWidget class, and i used alternatives for pass parameter, but the widget return for first number pass as parameter

Comment: Need more information.
Please include a code snipped for your separated class.

Comment: Please put code snippet here